# Job output not registering as python command line arg

Tags: github-actions

I have a worklow thati save in one of the jobs some outputs. in the next job i checkout the branch and try to run the a python script that accepts command line inputs.

when i try to pass the output, or rather a few outputs as command line variables, they don't register and i get and error saying sys.argv[2] out of bounds.

```
job1:
  runs-on: self-hosted
  outputs:
    name: ${{steps.step1.outputs.name}}
    age: ${{steps.step1.outputs.name}}

  steps:
    - id: step1
      run: | 
        export NAME="name"
        export AGE="1"
        echo "::set-output name=name::$NAME"
        echo "::set-output name=age::$AGE"

job2:
  runs-on: self-hosted
  
  steps:
   -name: test
    run: python app.py ${{needs.job1.outputs.name}} ${{needs.job1.outputs.age}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare that `job2` needs `job1`:

```yaml
  job2:
    needs: job1
```

From [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idoutputs):

> Job outputs are available to all downstream jobs that depend on this job.